# Where can I find a PPD file for a Laserjet 1005?

Tags: 11.10, hplip

I would like to install my HP LaserJet 1005 (in Ubuntu 11.10), which is old, yet very solid laser printer. However, there are no HPLIP component (PPD) for my printer.

Q1: Can I use a PPD file from another (previous) HPLIP release ?

if the answer is YES,

Q2: Where can I find a specific PPD file for my laser printer ?

Thank you in advance for hints and answers :)

Comment: It should be supported in 11.10 - ensure the hplip package is installed.  http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_1005_series.html

Comment: Yes, I installed a synaptic, and have checked if HPLIP is installed. During HPLIP automatic install I receive a message: error: Plug-in file does not match its digital signature. File may have been corrupted or altered. Error code: 2

Comment: try `sudo apt-get purge hplip` followed by `sudo apt-get install hplip` to clean up and reinstall the package.

Comment: Unfortunately, I got the same error message :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you are affected by this [launchpad issue](https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/171380).

The recommendation is to download the latest hplip package from the [HP website](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/gethplip.html)

Install the file:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sh hplip-3.11.10.run
```

Comment: There is no HPLIP for 11.10 yet. Should I download one for 11.04 ?

Comment: click the "Download HPLip" button - it will download the file hplip-3.11.10.run file which you can save to your Downloads folder.

Comment: Many thanks for recommendations ! Know everything is working right :) ! I didn't expect it will work with HPLIP for Ubuntu 11.04 (I don't know if there is a difference in HPLIP builds for 11.04 and 11.10 :)

Comment: It's 2015 and this still is the solution :)